# Integrate Angular 2 - existing application

Tags: angular

I want to integrate Angular 2 components inside an existing application using freemarker.

1 / The easiest way to do it is using iframe, so that I can use the angular 2 router to show the correct component based on the url. But it’s a little bit old fashioned… In that case, the Angular 2 application is a separate project than the existing application.

2 / Second way is to include the angular 2 application inside the existing one and create a root component per element to add in the html. But then you need to manually bootstrap components inside each html page..
For me, the best way would be to have one root component, and to tell this root component which component to display with the router. It would be nice also to use the lazy loading feature.

```
<root componentToDisplay='myComponent'></root>
```

Is it possible ? Or maybe there is a better idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find this solution in Google Search ? https://www.quora.com/Can-anybody-show-me-an-example-to-include-Angular-2-Typescript-with-existing-Spring-MVC-gradle-project

Comment: This solution is not perfect, you cannot bundle the whole app in one js file. It would be better to use angular-cli to build the angular 2 application and integrate it in the existing application.